# Heroku rejects Django app push

Tags: django, heroku

I've been developing a Heroku Django app for some time.  The latest update is getting an error on deployment:

```
$ git push staging staging:master
Counting objects: 168, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (52/52), done.
Writing objects: 100% (139/139), 19.98 KiB, done.
Total 139 (delta 96), reused 115 (delta 81)

-----> Heroku receiving push

 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


To git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] staging -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git'
```

Also: staging is my name for the heroku remote.

I've created a support ticket with Heroku, but have not received a response...  What should my next step be?  Reset the entire app and push a clean repo?

Comment: I've had this exact error (with no changes on my part), and it simply solved itself after a support ticket. I'm pretty sure references to this exact error suggest the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Yuji.  Good to know.  Hopefully I'll get a response to my support ticket soon then.

Comment: Assuming it was working before any obvious changes.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working all of a sudden last night.  No correspondence from Heroku though.